# MAC OS Ask for password before Force Quit application

Tags: macos, cocoa, kiosk

I am using cocoa to develop one application, which only allow administrator to close or quit my application, If my application running on guest account, I don't want guest to force quit it. Is there anyway to pop up password window when guest user try to force quit application.

I am using Kiosk Mode, when my application is in full screen, force quit was disabled, however when it is not in full screen, user can still force quit it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. Force quit is controlled by the system. If you were able to block it, it would allow you to create malware.

If you believe you have a valid use case, you should file an enhancement request at http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: Agreed - that's exactly what Kiosk Mode is for. Outside that mode nothing should block force-quit. As to an immediate solution, require Kiosk Mode.

Comment: If it is possible, I am thinking to create a background service to check my application when it is not show in the process list. What kind of service is good for this kind of task?

Comment: So, what, force the app to run again if the user kills it?

Answer (score 0):

Make your app as an agent (Application is agent=true)
Your app will not be on the list for user to force close.